# c++ macro parametrized (repetitive) expansion

Tags: c++, macros

Im using an enum set (c style) `id_t` to represent different test parameters T0, T1, ... These "parameters" are then "repeated" in two arrays; one `idsenum` holding the values T0, T1, ... themselves and another `idstxt` holding their textual representations "T0", "T1", ...

```
#define enumsetmacro  T0,  T1,  T2
enum id_t { enumsetmacro }; // enum proper 
vector<id_t> idsenum { enumsetmacro }; // in array => so can interate over values
vector<string> idstxt {  "T0",  "T1",  "T2" }; // textual repr. parallel to idsenum
```

Often I change the number of "parameters" and then have to modify both the enum set itself (via the macro `enumsetmacro`) and the textual representations in `idstxt`.

Question: Can some macro magic do this? Eg. imaginary code:

```
#define Nparams 3;
#define enumsetmacroids macroexpand("T", Nparams)
#define enumsetmacroidstxt macroexpand("\"T\"", Nparams)
enum id_t { enumsetmacroids }; // enum proper 
vector<id_t> idsenum { enumsetmacroids }; 
vector<string> idstxt {  enumsetmacroidstxt };
```

Where

```
macroexpand("T", 3) => (string) T0, T1, T2
macroexpand("\"T\"", 3) => (string) "T0", "T1", "T2"
```

Ok, I know this looks naive, probably not possible...?

Comment: Sure, but why not just generate the vectors' contents at runtime with a simple loop? I don't see the point of the enum either if it is to mirror plain numbers.

Comment: I prefer to use the enum for type checking and IDE assistance. Actually the above is a MRE and in reality the specific enum is used in multiple ways thru the code base. How could I produce a macro like the above? Or achieve the same result? Thx!

Comment: there is an alternative: https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using boost.preprocessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/for.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

#define DECL_ENUM_IDENTITY(a_r, a_dummy, a_elem) \
    a_elem,

#define DECL_ENUM_STR(a_r, a_dummy, a_elem) \
    BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(a_elem),

#define DECL_ENUM_IMPL(a_seq) \
    enum myid_t { BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECL_ENUM_IDENTITY, a_dummy, a_seq) }; \
    ::std::vector< myid_t > idsenum { BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECL_ENUM_IDENTITY, a_dummy, a_seq) }; \
    ::std::vector< ::std::string > idstxt { BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECL_ENUM_STR, a_dummy, a_seq) };

#define DECL_ELEMENT(a_r, a_index, a_name) \
    ( a_name ## a_index )

#define DECL_ENUM(a_name, a_count) \
    DECL_ENUM_IMPL(BOOST_PP_REPEAT(a_count, DECL_ELEMENT, a_name))

DECL_ENUM(T, 3)

int main()
{
    assert(3 == idsenum.size());
    assert(myid_t::T0 == idsenum.front());
    assert(myid_t::T2 == idsenum.back());
    assert(3 == idstxt.size());
    assert("T0" == idstxt.front());
    assert("T2" == idstxt.back());
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T3zWs5

Comment: Good idea, but still quite far from working properly: https://godbolt.org/z/jKzoG6

Comment: @MarekR It works properly, only `enum id_t` name conflicts with declaration from implicitly included `sys/types.h` header.

Comment: This is just tip of iceberg. Most probably he needs more then one enum.

Comment: Maybe you'll get some inspiraton from there:  https://codecraft.co/2014/11/25/variadic-macros-tricks//   It shows some neat tricks, including a FOR_EACH(....) , which you'd need to do what you want.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy It already works as intended. And i'm already using FOR_EACH from boost.

Comment: @user7860670  Sorry, I placed my comment in the wrong spot.  Was meant for OP.

Comment: @user7860670 how to end up with needing just DECL_ENUM(T, N) instead of DECL_ENUM((T0)(T1)...(TN_-1))? N is a "global" parameter in the codebase so would be nice to no having to change more than 1 place (where N is defined).

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised You can utilize `BOOST_PP_FOR` to generate input sequence with desired length and then concatenate `T` with number into a single name using `##` operator. To be honest it does not make much sense to have enum values named like x1 x2 x3. Have you considered using some sort of Ada-style integer range instead?

Comment: Thx!! Im using this specific nomenclature to conform to other code, and to have that correspondance be evident in eg. debugging sessions. Also T0, T1, ... in the example, in reality is TestParamSuiteA_0, TestParamSuiteA_1, ... But I understand your view that in general one might just a well use integers 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: @mrchance I've updated my answer showing how to generate sequence of desired length using `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`